# Error: Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: './node_modules/React/react'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is an image of the error and the console error...

[image: Screenshot of Error]

My code seems to be correct and the paths of the imports are good too, I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Notifications.js

```
import React from 'React'

const Notifications = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p>Notifications</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Notifications
```

ProjectList.js

```
import React from 'React'

const ProjectList = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="project-list section">
                <div className="card z-depth-0 project-summary">
                    <div className="card-content grey-text darken-3">
                        <span className="card-title">Project Title</span>
                        <p>Posted by Net Ninja</p>
                        <p className="grey-text">3rd September, 2018</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProjectList
```

Comment: It seems to work find when I just import Dashboard without its own imported Notifications and ProjectList imports, if that makes sense.

Comment: Imports are case-sensitive. In Notifications.js and ProjectList.js you are importing from `'React'` (uppercase "R"). This should be a lowercase "r".

Comment: In fact, the error message is "Cannot find 'React' module", which speaks for itself. There is no module React, but react

Comment: even I'm facing this error. I hate react but have to do as its the next gen.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
import React from 'React'
```

should be

```
import React from 'react'
```

You are trying to import `React` instead of `react`. The name of module is case-sensitive, in this case the name is [`react`](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this solution from Web-brackets.com 
all you need to do is just rename the imported library from React to react with small r like this (on the first line)

```
import React from 'react';
```

reference
https://web-brackets.com/discussion/6/-solved-cannot-find-file-index-js-does-not-match-the-corresponding-name-on-disk-react-js

Comment: Isn't this the accepted answer? What is new?

Answer (score 1):

Notification.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Notifications = () => {
return(
    <div>
        <p>Notifications</p>
    </div>
)
}

 export default Notifications
```

ProjectList.js

```
 import React from 'react'

 const ProjectList = () => {
 return(
    <div>
        <div className="project-list section">
            <div className="card z-depth-0 project-summary">
                <div className="card-content grey-text darken-3">
                    <span className="card-title">Project Title</span>
                    <p>Posted by Net Ninja</p>
                    <p className="grey-text">3rd September, 2018</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default ProjectList
```

module name is react not React and since imports are case-sensitive import React from 'React' is causing error

Comment: Yes, and it is what the accepted answer suggested

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is because you are not importing correctly. Like in my case it was :

```
import {Dropdown} from 'react-Bootstrap'
```

I corrected it to

```
import {Dropdown} from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Since import statement are case sensitive

Comment: This is what the accepted answer suggests

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was because I imported `React` not `react`
so it should go like this ..

```
import React from 'react'
```

Comment: Isn't this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The thing is that the compilation process uses caches to optimize build time. It's a internal thing to "Babel Loader". To make sure you get a fully refreshed compilation process by webpacker/babel, delete the folder "node_modules/.cache" and run `npm start` again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install react-router by using this command - `npm install react-router-dom`

Follow this link for further details. (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: This is not relevant to the question

Answer (score -2):

including when naming your file, in example you import App but the name on your file is app.js this wont allow the system to find the same name.